# how to create a bullet class to get starting position as it is drawn? seems like a simple fix

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx

i have a game class that im doing all the creations and drawing, but i have no idea how to get the starting point(x,y) of when the bullet is spawned.  because the x y is always changing.  I had the idea to create a bullet class but i have no idea how to change mygame around to fit it . All i need is the simple x,y coordiante of the spawned bullet any way to save it?  heres what i think my bullet class should maybe look like:

```
    public class Bullet {
private Circle circle;
private int startX;
private int startY;

public Bullet(int startX, int startY){
    circle = //create circle from startX and startY
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
}
//getters and setters here...
  }
```

here is my game class

```
                        public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture ballImage, bulletImage;
OrthographicCamera cam;
Circle ball;
Array <Circle> bullets;
//long lastShot;

@Override
public void create ()
{
    System.out.println("game created");
    ballImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png"));
    bulletImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bullet.png"));

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true,320,480);//true starts top left false starts bottom left

    batch = new SpriteBatch();  

    ball = new Circle();
    ball.radius=20;
    ball.x=320/2-ball.radius; // half screen size - half image
    ball.y=480/2-ball.radius;

    bullets = new Array<Circle>();
    spawnBullet();      
}

public void spawnBullet()
{
    Circle bullet = new Circle();
    bullet.radius=8;
    bullet.x=bullet.radius; // half screen size - half image
    bullet.y=MathUtils.random(0, 480-bullet.radius);
    bullets.add(bullet);
    System.out.println("x: "+bullet.x+" Y: "+bullet.y);     
}

@Override
public void render ()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(ballImage,ball.x-ball.radius,ball.y-ball.radius);
    for(Circle bullet: bullets)
    {
        batch.draw(bulletImage, bullet.x-bullet.radius, bullet.y-bullet.radius);
    }
    batch.end(); 

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {           
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3();
        pos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);
        cam.unproject(pos); 
        ball.y = pos.y ;    
    }


    if(ball.y<0+ball.radius)ball.y=ball.radius;
    if(ball.y>480-ball.radius)ball.y=480-ball.radius;

    Iterator<Circle> i = bullets.iterator();    

     while(i.hasNext())
    {

        Circle bullet = i.next();   
        //System.out.println("x2: "+bullet.x+" Y2: "+bullet.y);


        if(bullet.y>240){
        bullet.x++;
        bullet.y--;}

        bullet.x++;

        //right border collision
        if(bullet.x>320)
        {
            i.remove();
            spawnBullet();
        }
         //circle collision
            if(ball.overlaps(bullet))
            {
            i.remove();
            spawnBullet();
            }   
    } 



}   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you don't use your Bullet class at all. Your bullet class should extend Circle and then you can use that in your main class instead of Circle.

```
public class Bullet extends Circle {
    private int startX;
    private int startY;

    public Bullet(int startX, int startY){
        super();
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
    }
    // I added some constructors.
    public Bullet(Circle circle, int startX, int startY){
        super(circle);
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
    }

    public Bullet(float x, float y, float radius, int startX, int startY){
        super(x, y, radius);
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
    }

    public Bullet(Vector2 position, float radius, int startX, int startY){
        super(position, radius);
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
    }

    //getters and setters here...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195154/how-do-get-the-starting-point-of-each-bullet-libgdx-simple-game This question has been answered very well here. I suggest OP learns more about Java like subclasses and creating new classes.

Comment: yea and i dont know how to do it so i posted this...

Comment: can u just tell me how to access what i need in mygame class?

Comment: Your problem has really nothing to do with LibGDX. This is basic Java and your question shows really no research.